# getting empty input from tkinter text

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have been working on this seating chart do-hickiy for about 2-3 hours, and I came to a point where I was stuck. When I type a name into the text, gather the input, and assign it to a variable, it gives me an input that looks like this

```
['']
```

I have not been able to find anything on this problem and, I want to use a `Text()` and not `Entry()` because `Entry()` does not have a height attribute. If you can give me any hints or tips on how to figure out this problem or, have any other tips for my code please feel free to tell me how to make my code better :)

problem when I enter a name:

```
['']
Name Already exists
['', '']
Name Already exists
['', '', '']
Name Already exists
['', '', '', '']
```

Code:

```
#commands: add name , Run

#imports
import random
from time import sleep
from tkinter import *

#Console and background Handlers
Tables = 6
Names = []    

def AddNames():
    if NewNames in Names:
        print("Name Already exists")
    Names.append(NewNames)
    print(Names)

def Random():
    RandomNum = random.randrange(Tables)
    if RandomNum == 0:
        RandomNum = random.randrange(Tables)
    return RandomNum

def run():
    X = 0
    for i in Names:
        print(Names[X])
        print("Table: " + str(Random()))
        X += 1

#GUI Handler
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1024x768")

e = Text(root, bd=10, font=("Comic Sans MS", 50), width=15, height=2)
e.pack()
NewNames = e.get("1.0", 'end -1c')

AddNameButton = Button(root, text=("Add Name"), width=15, height=5, command=AddNames)
AddNameButton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `NewNames`  is initialized to an empty string and never modified.

Comment: NewNames = e.get("1.0", 'end -1c') is it not modified here?

Comment: Yes, it's set to the empty string, because at this point the user hasn't had a chance to type anything, because it's about 1 millisecond after the widget was created.

Comment: Oh, so I have to call add names when the user presses the button?

Comment: Oh, wait I can put the e.get() in add names. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's what you need to do.

Comment: Ha, It worked!!! Thanks Bryan!!!

Answer (score 0):

For the record, and mostly out of the comments (@Bryan Oakley):

The `AddNames` method, which is supposed to handle the input, does not actually check the content of the `e` `Text` widget.

The line:

```
NewNames = e.get("1.0", 'end -1c')
```

should be written inside of the `AddNames` method, so that every time the entry's content is meant to be checked, it is effectively read.

As it is in the original code, when the script is run, the content of `e` is put one time in `NewNames`, and never updated.

---

As a side note, it is (at least in Python) considered bad practice to name variables and functions with a cap. Function names should be in `lower_case_with_underscores`, and `CamelCase` should be reserved to class names. Local variable names are recommended to be in `lower_case_with_underscores` as well, but the most frequent naming style is `mixedCase`.

[Here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) is the reference, from PEP.

Comment: Thanks for the help with variable named :)